# Rich Text Editor - Strip Css Formatting

Tags: richtext-editor

The Strip Css Formatting option in Rich Text Editor does not remove all inline styles. Using the following markup:

```
<h3 style="color: #222222; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 1em 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 1.3em;">Q: What is the outlook for the U.S. economy, as well as fiscal and monetary policy?</h3>
<p style="color:#ff0000; background-color: #000;"> HELLO </p>
<p style="color:#ffff00; background-color:#000;"> <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;">jello </span></p>
```

Results in:

```
<h3>Q: What is the outlook for the U.S. economy, as well as fiscal and monetary policy?</h3>
<p> HELLO </p>
<p> <span style="color: #ffffff;">jello </span></p>
```

As you can see the last inline style was not stripped out. Is there any explanation for that behavior?

Sitecore version 10.1.

Comment: Sitecore version?

Comment: @JonKoivula 10.1. I have updated it in the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard behavior of Telerik RTE I'm afraid.

`color` attribute from `<span>` tags is never removed.

You can check that on online demo page of Telerik RTE: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Switch to html mode there, paste your html and try clearing content - you will see that you can remove all other styles, but `color` on `<span>` will never be removed.